# The brightness on the Windows 7 partition of my Macbook Pro won't change. How do I fix this?

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning, macbook, boot-camp

Since installing Windows 7 + Bootcamp on my Macbook Pro, I've been unable to change the brightness. Pressing the F1/F2 keys makes the brightness graphic appear and a bar moves up and down, but the brightness of the screen remains constant. Even trying to modify the brightness through the control panel yields no results at all. The brightness control still works completely fine on the OS X partition. This problem has existed for almost a year, and I've rebooted my computer countless times. Still, the problem persists.

Why won't my brightness change, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you try re-installing the Bootcamp drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange or inconsistent hardware behavior may be related to the NVRAM (for Intel-based Macs) or PRAM (for PowerPC-based) of your Macbook. Issues related to NVRAM/PRAM may include USB ports that don't function, speaker volume misbehaving, strange things happening with your screen or screen resolution, etc. If you're experiencing issues in any of these areas, it may be worth it to try resetting your NVRAM/PRAM.

From [Apple's support site](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379):

> 1. Shut down your Mac.
> 2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P, and R. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in step
>      4.
> 3. Turn on the computer.
> 4. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys before the gray screen appears.
> 5. Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.
> 6. Release the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I have a MacBook Air running Windows 7 with bootcamp. The brightness control buttons no longer work after the 310.xx driver. Issue has been fixed after alittle bit of research. Thanks all who participated the bits and piece of this resolution. Start off by installing the latest NVIDIA drivers and latest Bootcamp. Yes you heard me correctly. No need to roll back, the latest and greatest worked for me. version 337.88

1. Go to control Panel, then device manager, then under "Monitors" I've Disabled the "Generic PNP monitor"
2. Open regedit and go to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Class/{4D36E968-E325-11CE-B FC1-08002BE10318}/0000
3. Add a new DWORD called "EnableBrightnessControl" and set the value to 1.
4. Reboot and the brightness keys should work again.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2669574